# How can I grab the stats of load-balanced servers?

Tags: iis, log-files, awstats, stats

I've got two servers with IIS 6 and I have to set up a statistics report for the website that is hosted in both servers.  load balanced.
Tried AW Stats but it is a pain.
I'm using SmarterSTATS now , it sounds good.
But it's like the servers logs are not producing numbers that this service could understand.
Confused. N00b. Complete n00b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awstats or SmarterSTATS should expect logfiles in "combined" format. Modify IIS to create files with that format.

Comment: I used SmarterStats, it worked well, and I had to reprocess my logs several times until I saw the accurate numbers. Took it's time.  Bad thing is I can't create reports to all my users to see.